# Celery periodic task for many objects

Tags: django, celery

In My models I have `Campaign` entity and `User` entity ..

I want to take the minutes of the `created` field of the `Campaign` entity and run an hourly task with it for every campaign, the celery task should get the users visiting the campaign in the last hour and choice one of them randomly to win money from the campaign sold .
Knowing that the periodic task should be a function called in `celery.py` file.

What should I do ?

Thanks in advance.